# How to show datetimepicker correctly in /bootstrap 4.6 app?

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I want to add datetimepicker into my in my laravel 8 app with jquery 3.4/bootstrap 4.6 , but adding m

```
@section('headerscripts')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{admin_assets}}/css/jquery.fancybox.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{admin_assets}}/css/selectize.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" integrity="sha256-yMjaV542P+q1RnH6XByCPDfUFhmOafWbeLPmqKh11zo=" crossorigin="anonymous" />


    {{--    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">--}}

@stop


...

@section('footerscripts')

    <script src="{{admin_assets}}/js/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{!!admin_assets!!}/js/pages/crud/forms/widgets/select2.js"></script>
    <script src="{!!admin_assets!!}/js/pages/crud/forms/editors/summernote.js"></script>

    <script src="{!!admin_assets!!}/js/pages/crud/forms/editors/AutoNumeric/AutoNumeric.js"></script>

    <script src="{{admin_assets}}/js/jquery.caret.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js" integrity="sha256-5YmaxAwMjIpMrVlK84Y/+NjCpKnFYa8bWWBbUHSBGfU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

...

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#dob').datetimepicker();
...

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="user_id">
                        User <span class="text-danger">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="input-group" id="dob">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Date Of Birth">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

But having datetimepicker on form(without any errors in browser's console)
it looks like icons are not supported : https://prnt.sc/1r10yxn

If to uncomment line in

```
@section('headerscripts')
section
    {{--    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">--}}
```

all icons of datetimepicker are shown ok, but I have some design breaks on my page.
I think that is a not goodidea to add 3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css into my bootstrap 4.6  for icons support.
If there is a way to fix it correctly?

Maybe are some some bettre datetimepicker libraries for my app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not wise to use both version of Bootstrap. Some css elements may be changed or deprecated that cause your design broken.

I suggest using `daterangepicker` at [here](https://www.daterangepicker.com/)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />

<input id="my-calendar" type="text" name="date">
<i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> <!-- Using Font Awesome -->

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<script>
     $('#my-calendar').daterangepicker({
         "singleDatePicker": true,
         "showDropdowns": true,
         locale: { format: 'DD/MM/YYYY' },
     });
</script>
```